# Eligibility for non ECR passport

Tags: passports, india, ecr

My mother is 49 years 5 months old and studied unt 7th class. Is she eligible for non ECR ([Emigration Clearance Required](https://pickyourtrail.com/blog/ecr-vs-ecnr-categories-of-indian-passport/)) passport?

As of now I applied in the ECR category. Is there any benefit of it?

Comment: can she wait until she is 50? Then she will definitely be eligible https://pickyourtrail.com/blog/ecr-vs-ecnr-categories-of-indian-passport/